# why is this C program not working correctly?

Tags: c

I tried to create my version of functions `gets()` and `puts()` for learning about them. The program which i wrote correctly displays the string but also some garbage characters.

Why does this happen?

```
/* xgets and xputs function */
/*Author : Swapnil Jain */
#include<stdio.h>
void xgets(char *);
void xputs(char *);
int main()
{
 char str[25];
 xgets(str);
 printf("\n");
 xputs(str);
 return 0;
}

void xgets(char *a)
{
 printf("Enter string\n");
 while(1)
 {
  scanf("%c",a);
  if(*a != '\n')
    a++;
  else 
    break;
 }
 a = '\0';
}

void xputs(char *a)
{
 while(1)
 {
  printf("%c",*a);
  if(*a != '\0')
    a++;
  else
    break;
 }
}
```

Input string:

```
Hello how are you
```

Output string:

```
Hello how are you
D�
```

Comment: Show us the input string and the garbage

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. This seems like an attempt to null-terminate the input, only this particular expression at the end of `xgets()` has no effect

```
    a = '\0';
```

It sets the value of the `a` pointer itself to 0.

Just add a `*` in front of `a` to set the character pointed-to by `a` to 0:

```
    *a = '\0';
```

---

⚠ <sub>Note: Your code is susceptible to a buffer overflow because `str` has a fixed length of 25, which is not checked in `xgets`. You should pass the length of `str` as a second argument to `xgets` and check it there.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Better always initialized all the location of a char array with null character which is equivalent to 0 line below.

```
  char str[25];
  memset(str, 0, sizeof(str);
```

Also correct your code line below:-

```
 a = '\0';  to *a = '\0';
```

This will fix your problem.